# Django: get user related field value in HTML to

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

I am trying to show the related field of the user on the webpage using Django.

I have models:

Models.py

```
class Companies(models.Model):
    company_name = models.TextField()
    company_email = models.EmailField()
    company_owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 def __str__(self):
        return self.company_name


class Cars(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey('Companies', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    car_model = models.TextField()
```

views.py:

```
class UserCompanyCars(ListView):
    model = Cars
    template_name = 'home/company_cars.html'
    context_object_name = 'cars'

    slug_field ="username"
    paginate_by = 100

    def get_queryset(self):

        company_n = get_object_or_404(Companies, company_owner=self.request.user)
        return Cars.objects.filter(company=company_n)
```

and my html is:

```
{% extends 'home/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<h1 class="mb-3"> Cars of {{user.Companies.company_name}}</h1>
    {% for car in cars %}
            <div class="media-body">
                <div class = "article-metadata">
                <p class="article-content">{{car.company}}</p>
                    <a href="{% url 'Car-Detail' user.username car.id%}">{{car.car_model}}</a>
                <p class="article-content">{{car.car_carry }}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

What I am trying to achieve is to write out "Cars of TestCompany (26)" on the webpage, but I cannot figure out how to get the Company_Name which is owned by the user. I have been trying all those Companies.objects... variations but none of them seem to work.

Comment: You have a typo in your html: Comapny instead of Company... maybe it's just like that in the question and not your code?

Comment: @MeL yes it was just in the question as I wanted to post what I think was the closest to the solution, fixed it and still not functioning

Comment: @arjun I don't get any error message as the browser is just showing me line "Cars of (26)". So it is not retuning the company name before the number of cars existing

Comment: It's also uppercase instead of lowercase. You should reproduce your exact code here, otherwise it's difficult to know where the problem is...

Comment: @MeL Reproduced the exact code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (sample code taken from my project):

```
  category = get_object_or_404(Category, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])       
  context['allcategories'] = MyPosts.objects.filter(category=category)
  return context
```

This will filter all posts in the database based on certain categories. You can apply the same solution to your code.

If this solution does not work, please try to give more details about the problem.

Comment: @Mel maybe correct i did not pay attention to the name, try to correct typo and check if that resolved the issue.

Comment: @Mel so I would need to create a "def get_queryset(self):" for this as well?